# Possible to add an append method to a slice

Tags: arrays, go

I have something like the following type structure below:

```
type Set []*Element

func (set *Set) AppendElements(elements []*Elements) {
    // ?
}
```

Obviously simply appending elements to a slice is not very useful. However, the actual function takes some value, does some business logic, and then appends the elements. However, I am facing the difficulty that modifications to the slice inside of the method to not actually change the value of the slice to outside callers, because the append method allocates a new slice that is not seen by the callers.

Is there a way to append to the slice in a method or should the slice be wrapped in a struct or something else?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Element int
type Set []*Element

func (ptr *Set) AppendElements(elements []*Element) {
    set := *ptr
    set = append(set, elements...)
}

func main() {
    i := Element(1)
    var set Set
    set.AppendElements([]*Element{&i})

    for _, el := range set {
        fmt.Println(el)
    }
}
```

More specifically, the above prints nothing.

Comment: You have a `*Set` pointer, so you can modify it. It would help to show how are you are managing to _not_ modify it.

Comment: @JimB The append function does not work with pointers. A runnable example is posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're modifying the slice, but you never assign it back to the pointer.

```
func (ptr *Set) AppendElements(elements []*Element) {
    set := *ptr
    set = append(set, elements...)
    *ptr = set
}
```

Usually though, one would dereference the pointer directly in the `append` statement:

```
func (set *Set) AppendElements(elements []*Element) {
    *set = append(*set, elements...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and please excuse my incompetence as I have not had much experience with c-style languages.